# using ifelse in data.table in R to assign values

Tags: r, if-statement, data.table

lets imagine i want to create a data.table with three columns from the `mtcars` package. I want to have the `cost` (which for illustrational purposes is the sum of hp), grouped by `gear`. The problem is the third variable `costlimited`- it depends on a previously specified `budget`. If `cost` > `budget`, then `costlimited` = `budget` , otherwise `costlimited` = `cost`.

```
budget <- c(2000)
mtcarsTOTAL <- mtcars[, ':=' ( cost = sum(hp), costlimited = ifelse(cost > budget, budget, cost) ), by = gear]
```

Additionally i want to add an column that contains an 1 if cost > budget and 0 if not. The desired outcome is

```
    gear cost costLimited highCost
[1,]    4 1074        1074        0
[2,]    3 2642        2000        1
[3,]    5  978         978        0
```

The emphasis is to do this in data.table, which i am currently learning by doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `ifelse` here. (BTW there is `fifelse` from `data.table`.)

Try

```
library(data.table)
budget <- c(2000)

dt <- as.data.table(mtcars)[, .(cost = sum(hp)), by = gear]
dt[, costlimited := pmin(budget, cost)]
dt[, highCost := +(budget == costlimited)]
dt
#   gear cost costlimited highCost
#1:    4 1074        1074        0
#2:    3 2642        2000        1
#3:    5  978         978        0
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
budget <- c(2000)

mtcars <- tibble(
  gear = c(4, 3, 5), 
  cost = c(1074, 2642, 978 ) 
)

mtcarsTOTAL <- mtcars
mtcarsTOTAL$costLimited <- ifelse(mtcarsTOTAL$cost > budget, budget, mtcarsTOTAL$cost )
mtcarsTOTAL$highCost <- ifelse(mtcarsTOTAL$cost > budget, 1, 0 )
```

Comment: Does your answer actually require `tidyverse`? It seems like an entirely base R solution, except for choosing to use `tibble` instead of `data.frame`. Is that accurate?

Comment: @divibisan It doesn`t require tidyverse, you are right. Thanks.